# How can I include a non-participant's details in the receipts?

Tags: webform-civicrm, email, receipts

I have setup an event on a webform with 2 contacts. 
Parent: Contact1 - 
Child: contact2

- Contact1 is there only to create a relationship with CONATCT2 and not a participant of the event.
- Contact2 is the actual participant.

When the receipt is triggered after successful payment, obviously Details of Contact1 does not show in the receipt because he is not a participant.

How can I include the details of Contact1 in the receipt template please?
Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a slightly different question but you should be able to use the same technique as described here, i.e. use the api in your message template to look up the info:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/29232/181