# Which tokens are available for activity?

Tags: activities, tokens

I want to send a reminder to the assignee of an activity and I want to add in the message the phone number (preventing the assignee to log into CRM and spare clicks).

I found these tokens from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php#L486):

```
{activity.activity_id}
{activity.subject}
{activity.details}
{activity.activity_date_time}
```

and they work properly with CiviRules but they are not enough. It would be great to have extra tokens with e-mail, phone number and a few others.

Are they available right now or could they be available? If needed we could write an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use smarty to get contact details of the target of the activity.

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31516/8748

snippet:

```
{if $contact.activity_id}
  {crmAPI var='activityResult' entity='Activity' action='getsingle' return="target_contact_id" id=$contact.activity_id}
  {crmAPI var='contactResult' entity='Contact' action='getsingle' return="phone,email" id=$activityResult.target_contact_id}
  <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>{$contactResult.phone}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>{$contactResult.email}</td>
  </tr>
{/if}
```

Comment: simple and efficient. Thanks Anatole

Answer (score 2):

This extension could possibly help - https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-tokens